# Raising a JavaScript event when a responsive nav collapse kicks in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How can I call a JavaScript function when the 'nav collapse' feature of a responsive design kicks in?

Specifically I'm looking at [this](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) Bootstrap example. Resizing the browser window will toggle it on/off. I'm sure it's somewhere in Bootstrap's JS that checks the browser's size.

Is there a simple way I could do something like `$(window).resize(x);` and in that function check to see whether the collapse has happened or not?

Comment: its called css3 media queries. You dont necessarily need js for this.

Comment: I thought so but my scenario is such that I need to modify the CSS of a single element for when the collapse toggles on/off. It's hacky but I don't know CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [css media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) are used.

For example: `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { /* do stuff */ }`

Listen for the window resize event in javascript and do whatever you like for the same circumstances if you want to do something in JS:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){

    var currentWidth = $(this).width();

    if(currentWidth > 768 && currentWidth < 979){
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

However, just as @user1721135 mentioned, your example uses only css, which is all that's needed in that case.

[This](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) will get you started.